# How can I restrict access to methods, only allowing a particular assembly access to them?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

Is there an attribute I can use to restrict access to methods or assemblies?

(I'm working in C#, .Net 3.5)

e.g.

```
[RestrictionAttribute(//Specify an assembly or a key or something here)]
Public void MyMethod()
{
    //Do something...
}
```

I want to add an 'access layer' of code on top of some business assemblies where some authenticating etc. can take place and want to make sure the business assemblies can not be accessed directly, only through the access layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `internal` keyword instead of `public` for your class(es) and then use the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute.

Thomas

Answer (score 2):

Without using attributes, you can do something like:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security;

protected const string AUTHORIZED_CALLER
    = "YourTrustedAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7bb5a56c4391e80f";

public void MyMethod()
{
    if (Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName != AUTHORIZED_CALLER) {
        throw new SecurityException("Unauthorized method call.");
    }

    // Now do something.
}
```